# I am facing issue while testing the lambda function after uploading zip file

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, file-upload, lambda, .net-core

Hi I am trying to execute lambda function after successfully building and uploading the zip to lambda.

It is giving me error as : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMDIR.jpg)

The which I am getting is as below:

> {   "errorType": "LambdaException",   "errorMessage": "Could not find
>   the specified handler assembly with the file name 'LambdaTest,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The assembly should be located
>   in the root of your uploaded .zip file." }

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, it was a vpn issue where the security groups were not configured properly. Thanks!

Comment: Which security groups?

Comment: @ashish I removed vpn configuration and tested it. Could you please explain error which you are facing.